# How to handle all UNICODE characters with pylaTex?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, latex, pdflatex

I have a web site running a flask app (python 3) and when I try to generate a pdf I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./web/frontend/printr.py", line 204, in generate_files
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylatex/document.py", line 228, in generate_pdf
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['latexmk', '--pdf', '--interaction=nonstopmode', 'a05f271c-1a7b-4996-9533-1c8ff17a90bf.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 12

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./web/frontend/views.py", line 690, in report
  File "./web/frontend/printr.py", line 206, in generate_files
  File "/env/flask3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylatex/document.py", line 228, in generate_pdf
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['xetex', '--interaction=nonstopmode', 'a05f271c-1a7b-4996-9533-1c8ff17a90bf.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The code:

```
try:
    doc.generate_pdf(file,clean_tex=True)
except Exception as e:
    doc.generate_pdf(file,clean=False,compiler='xetex')
```

The option clean=False dumps many files included the *.tex, so using the command line on server I tried again (pdflatex file_name.text) e got the specific error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Checking one solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304939/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u2010) I add the following line in the file manually:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}% support older LaTeX version
```

And worked!

**But How I can do this using PYLATEX?** Have another way to handle with this cases? Because in my opinion It's too hard to set all UnicodeCharacter that cannot be handle with latex.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed changing the compiler. XeTeX and LuaTeX will let you input unicode without complaining.

```
    if output == 'pdf':
        try:
            doc.generate_pdf(file,clean_tex=True)
        except Exception as e:
            doc.generate_pdf(file,clean=False,compiler='lualatex')
    else:
        doc.generate_tex(file)
```